# How to enable No Late Submissions State for Google Classroom using Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-classroom

I was trying to set `NO_LATE_SUBMISSIONS`, option to the classWork for Google Classrooms using the Apps Script, using the following method. It is giving an error saying there is no "setLateSubmissionPolicy" method. How do I set the No Late Submission option? I would appreciate it if you let me know how to set that option on the Classwork.

I was trying to do this, and it is not working.

```
var classWork = Classroom.newCourseWork();
classWork.setLateSubmissionPolicy(Classroom.newLateSubmissionPolicy().setLateSubmissionPolicyState("NO_LATE_SUBMISSIONS"));
```

Comment: I would like to confirm that your goal is to not allow the students to submit their classwork if it's already past its due date using Google Apps Script. Would that be correct?

Comment: That is correct.